# Social media impact on Trump's presidency

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, media, public-opinion

It is difficult for me to realise really how much social media content approves or rejects some political party or person. The content is automatically generated and will always fit what the reader reads most. The consequence is that I have no idea about what most people's position is. And the number of votes does not give the whole story.

Is there any study about which social media content has more impact: the pro-Trump or the anti-Trump?

Comment: From your comments to Bradley's answer: What do you mean by *social media*? As I understand it, it involves those media where the content is provided/distributed by the users, even if it is just by linking to other sources. For example, Twitter, Facebook, etc. TV stations, newspapers, etc., even if online, would be called *mass media*.

Comment: Sorry, this is impossible to asnwer objectively as-is because you didn't define "impact" in any meaningful way. Most people vote for a party based on their existing total affiliation (basically, what their tribe votes for, on a crude approximation level), not what they read on Facebook - except, they usually see same things on FB that their tribe sees anyway.

Comment: @SJuan, I share your definition of social media

Comment: @user4012, I am sure that there are measurable quantities that quantify "impact". I do not know them, but I hope answers can describe them.

Comment: "Presidency" refers to the time, after he became President? Assume close to zero. Some people watch CNN others Fox.

Answer (score -1):

Social Media is much more than clicking and reading.  It is about how many ads that go before the eyes of readers.  Those who are most active on Social Media tend to be more pliable in their political views based on their lack of real world experience.  (They spend more time in front of screens than their cohorts that are busy doing other things)  They are also more readily available to watch the ads and buy the products that are just a click away.
A social media company attracts the advertisers that cater to this audience by keeping them clicking on those pages that make them feel that they are smart.  More page views, more sales, more ads.  So, catering to people who exist on the fringes of the day to day world in their online bubbles is good business. Rumors, Conspiracy Theories, and outright lies are much more believable for someone who has little interaction with the rest of the world. Unfortunately, many in the Mass Media and Political circles believe that Twitter and Facebook reflect the perceptions of many more people than they actually do.

Comment: We know. But that's not answering the question. Which camp is influenced more by social media: The pro-Trump or the anti-Trump side? And can you back up which side is more influenced by some hard data from a reliable source?